# cleaner arbitage calcuator in php

Tags: php, calculator

Im trying to learn php and as a small project i thought id try and make an [Arbitrage calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrage), for the basic workings of it ive been building it based on this [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjhmNC-l_CS3dC1TSkg5VTBpQUtIQ3NpNERYRXZIb2c&usp=sharing).

Ive made a start on it but i feel its a bit of a "dirty" piece of work and could been slicker, but im not sure how i could improve it, any ideas.

This is my code (excuse the `echo` block this is just for my output in Code Runner, in practice the whole `if` block would be inside a function returning an array which could be `echo`'ed out in the view)

```
$number1 = 1.2;
$number2 = 8;

$total_stake = 100;


        if ($total_stake / $number1 > 0 && $total_stake / $number2 > 0) {

            $num1_stake = $total_stake / $number1;
            $num2_stake = $total_stake / $number2;

            $num1_profit =  $total_stake - $num1_stake;
            $num2_profit =  $total_stake - $num2_stake;


            echo "
            //// NUMBER 1 ////
            Num 1 Stake - $num1_stake
            Num 1 Profit - $num1_profit

            //// NUMBER 2 ////
            Num 2 Stake - $num2_stake
            Num 2 Profit - $num2_profit
            ";



        } else {
            echo "There is no arb opportunity";
        }
```

Comment: seems pretty clean to me , what have your thought to make cleaner?

Comment: Shouldn't this get moved to 'Code Review'?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing came up in my mind is to make those 2 calculations lines in one line
as following:

```
$num1_profit =  $total_stake - ($num1_stake = $total_stake / $number1);
$num2_profit =  $total_stake - ($num2_stake = $total_stake / $number2);
```

I don't know if it could be defined as 'cleaner'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks clean, but has two small issues.

1. If one of `$number1` or `$number2` is 0, you'll get a 'division by zero' error.
2. You're calculating the quotient twice. You can solve this by calculating the quotiont  *before* the `if` statement:

   ```
   $number1 = 1.2;
   $number2 = 8;

   $total_stake = 100;

   if ($number1 != 0 && $number2 != 0) {
       $num1_stake = $total_stake / $number1;
       $num2_stake = $total_stake / $number2;

       if ($num1_stake > 0 && $num2_stake > 0) {
           $num1_profit =  $total_stake - $num1_stake;
           $num2_profit =  $total_stake - $num2_stake;

           echo "
           //// NUMBER 1 ////
           Num 1 Stake - $num1_stake
           Num 1 Profit - $num1_profit

           //// NUMBER 2 ////
           Num 2 Stake - $num2_stake
           Num 2 Profit - $num2_profit
           ";

       } else {
           echo "There is no arb opportunity";
       }
   }
   ```

If you want to handle variable numbers of stakes, put them into an array.

```
$numbers     = array(1.2, 8);
$total_stake = 100;

calculate/$total_stake, $numbers);

function calculate($total_stake, $numbers)
{
    $profit = array();
    foreach ($numbers as $key => $number) {
        if ($number == 0) {
            echo 'Number cannot be 0';
            return;
        }
        stake = $total_stake / $number;

        if ($stake > 0) {
            $profit[$key] = $total_stake - $stake;

            printf("//// NUMBER %1$d ////\nNum %1$d Stake  - %2$f\nNum %1$d Profit - %3$f\n\n",
                $key,
                $stake,
                $profit[$key]
            );
        }
        if (empty($profit)) {
            echo "There is no arb opportunity";
        }
    }
}
```